# send information secured over ssl using a php form POST function

Tags: php, forms, email, ssl, encryption

I have created a verry easy website, just displaying some articles.
This website is protected with an SSL certificate.
I ham using a Postivie SSL CA 2 certificate.
When im visiting my website i see that all pages are secured with the ssl protocol (https).
Then, when i get to my contact form, there seems to be information that is not encrypted.

The form im using is verry basic.
I ask the people to enter name, email and a message.
On submit, i read these variables using the POST function of PHP.
Whenever the form is filled out correctly, i send an email to myself and a copy to the user.
I do this using the php mail() function.

Could anyone tell me what the reason is that my certificate tells me there is no encryption?
Is it because i dont handle the POST function correctly?
Or am i supposed to use a different mail() function for the encryption? Maybe there is something else i am forgetting?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some elements in the page that are not on a secure URL: images, videos, CSS files, JavaScript files, or other content. If you serve a page on a secure domain and you have an image in your HTML that is explicitly from a non-secure domain :

```
<img src="http://www.example.com/image.png">
```

That makes your page not secure as it includes a non secure element, even if your certificate is valid for the domain which is serving the web page.

If you are using a JS library served from a CDN, make sure you use the secure URL (`https://`). Most CDNs provide secure alternatives for most common JS libraries.

Comment: I have changed the location of "action" in my form including the full https address, now everything is solved. Thank you